# Multi line replacement with Sed

Tags: sed

I have a file like this:

```
function a() {
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Now I need to replace all text between `function a() {` and `}` with some other text

I tried several ways found here, but they all failed. I hope I could get the **explanation** along with an answer.

P.S. the trick need to be compatible with both OS X and GNU Sed.

Comment: Is `doSomething();` currently a single line?

Comment: Show us your attempt, the result, and the intended result

Comment: sed is always the wrong tool for any job that involves operating on multiple lines simultaneously. If `sed 's/doSomething()/foobar/' file` isn't all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide better sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EtanReisner No, multiple line

Comment: In line with Ed Morton's comment notice how every answer you've received so far has dealt with exactly one line (and exactly that line) of input? This is why it is *crucial* to give *exact* real-life input when asking questions of this sort. As Ed also says `sed` is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a standard substitution :

```
sed -i 's/\(\<\)doSomething()/\1somethingElse()/' your_file
```

We use the word boundary to delimit your string :

```
\(\<\)doSomething()
```

And then we replace that string with your new string (including the captured word boundary) :

```
\1somethingElse()
```

The `-i` flag stands for : inline replacement

---

I used this sample file :

```
function a() {
  doSomething();
doSomething();
  foo();doSomething();
}
```

Output :

```
function a() {
  somethingElse();
somethingElse();
  foo();somethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^function a() {/,/}/{
   /^[[:blank:]]*doSomething();/ c\
Replace with\
whaterver you want \
where new line are backslash \
at the end for multiline.
   }' YourFile
```

- replace the line of `doSomething` inside function a() paragraph by some other line(s)
- Highly depend on content of function a() (assuming there is no ending `}` line *inside* the function)

Comment: `c\ ` (with backslash) is posix compliant, `c` is GNU sed only. If it fail, you can still use temporary file and `r`action instead.